# Visual Studio 2017 is intercepting/capturing my hotkeys for push-to-talk

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, hotkeys, discord

I've recently used both Ventrilo and Discord for push-to-talk communication with another developer. Currently my Right <kbd>CTRL</kbd> is my hotkey to enable talk, and one of my mouse buttons is mapped to the Right <kbd>CTRL</kbd>. I can use the mouse button to talk in any program EXCEPT for Visual Studio 2017 (I believe it's happening in 2015 as well). It appears to be intercepting my buttons and not letting it through to other applications.

Is there a setting in VS to turn this off, or another solution that would enable me to be in VS and get to my push-to-talk?

I've tried mapping different keys and using different mapping software(XMouse and Roccat Swarm) with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Hurray! I updated my VS two days ago and it seemed to fix the problem! I haven't changed anything else since then... weird.